# Как найти индекс наибольшего числа в двумерном списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import copy

A = []
x = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in range(x[1] - 1):
    A.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

print(A)

arr = copy.deepcopy(A)

arr.sort(reverse=True)
arr[0].sort(reverse=True)
max = arr[0][0]
print(arr)

i = 0
j = 0

for j in range(x[1] - 1):
    for i in A[j - 1]:
        if A[j][i] - 1 == max:
            i = i
        else:
            i = 0
print(i)
print(j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение для случая прямоугольной матрицы (когда все строки матрицы имеют одинаковую длину).

```
In [81]: from itertools import chain

In [82]: m = [[64, 84, 44, 77, 50, 71],
    ...: [49, 28, 99, 97, 21, 38],
    ...: [21, 89, 40, 91, 15, 17],
    ...: [97, 28, 20, 84, 34, 32],
    ...: [69, 62, 51, 31, 91, 83]]

In [83]: tmp = list(chain(*m))

In [84]: idx = max(range(len(tmp)), key=tmp.__getitem__)

In [85]: i,j = divmod(idx, len(m[0]))

In [86]: print(f"Максимальный элемент - m[{i}, {j}]:\t{m[i][j]}")
```

---

```
Максимальный элемент - m[1, 2]: 99
```

Answer (score 3):

Используя идею хранения индекса строка-столбец для каждого элемента из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/991308) **godva** и *выпрямления* матрицы:

```
from random import choices
from itertools import chain, product

rcnt, ccnt = 5, 6
m_ranges = range(rcnt), range(ccnt)

m = [choices(range(100), k=ccnt) for _ in range(rcnt)]

print('Value: {}, index: {}'.format(*max(zip(chain(*m), product(*m_ranges)))))
```

Comment: Элегантное решение !

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

rows, cols = 5, 8
m = [[random.randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

key_func = lambda item: item[-1]
result = max(((i, *max(enumerate(row), key=key_func)) for i, row in enumerate(m)), key=key_func) # (row, col, value)
print("Max value {}. Index ({}, {})".format(result[-1], result[0], result[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `li` на Ваш список:

```py
import random

li = [[random.randint(10, 99) for i in range(6)] for j in range(5)]

print('Список:', *li, sep='\n', end='\n\n')

max_el = li[0][0]
max_i = (0, 0)
for i in range(len(li)):
    for j in range(len(li[i])):
        x = li[i][j]
        if x > max_el:
            max_el = x
            max_i = (i, j)

print('Максимальный элемент: {}  # {}'.format(max_i, li[max_i[0]][max_i[1]]), end='')
```

*Один из возможных stdout:*

```html
Список:
[64, 84, 44, 77, 50, 71]
[49, 28, 99, 97, 21, 38]
[21, 89, 40, 91, 15, 17]
[97, 28, 20, 84, 34, 32]
[69, 62, 51, 31, 91, 83]

Максимальный элемент: (1, 2)  # 99
```